# gnuplot plot loop through axes

Tags: loops, gnuplot, axes

While plotting in gnuplot, is there a way to loop through axes?
Something like this:

`var_axes="x1y1 x1y2"
plot for [i=1:2] datafile using 1:2 axes word(var_axes,i)`

It complains: "axes must be x1y1, x1y2, x2y1 or x2y2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct your `plot` command in a string variable, and then use `eval` to execute it:

```
var_axes="x1y1 x1y2"
cmd = "plot "
do for [i=1:2] {
   cmd = cmd . "datafile using 1:2 axes "   . word(var_axes,i)
   if (i < 2) {
     cmd = cmd . ", "
   }
}
eval cmd
```

Comment: Perfect! `eval` really works!
Only struggled a bit because the "datafile" must stay between apostrophes:
`cmd = cmd . "'datafile' using 1:2 axes "   . word(var_axes,i)`